What's wrong in my PrivacyInfo file in iOS App? I still recieve a mail with TMS-91053: Missing API declaration when upload an update
I am recieving this mail when I upload an update of my iOS APP:

ITMS-91053: Missing API declaration - Your app’s code in the “mi coche
eléctrico” file references one or more APIs that require reasons,
including the following API categories:
NSPrivacyAccessedAPICategoryUserDefaults. While no action is required
at this time, starting May 1, 2024, when you upload a new app or app
update, you must include a NSPrivacyAccessedAPITypes array in your
app’s privacy manifest to provide approved reasons for these APIs used
by your app’s code.

I have created the PrivacyInfo with this information (the requested in mail), but this mail is recieved even with this PrivacyInfo file in the upadatee app.

Any idea what is wrong on it? Thanks in advance

Have you checked if any of your dependencies (I.E. SDKs) are using this API as well? If so, they will need to provide a privacy manifest as well.

Thanks for the answer but there’s no dependencies involved ‍♂️

Please do not put SOLVED in the title. You accepted an answer. That indicates that it is solved.

@Fattie - My comments tried to assist by gathering more information about the problem and before a proper answer was given. But thanks for encouraging people to provide assistance.

I was having the same problem, this happens because your root project contains an accent, if you carry out the same process removing the accent from the project name you will not receive a warning from Apple.
A few days ago I opened a ticket to Apple, as I believe this is a flaw in their algorithm which, due to the fact that the name of the project contains an accent, cannot identify the PrivacyInfo file, but so far I have not received any response.
I suggest that you compile your project without an accent and before uploading it to Apple, change the app name property directly in Xcode (info > Blunde display name).

Thanks a lot ... that was the problem. Removed the accent in the root and "write manually the app name in "Bundle display name"... and no more warnings. As you said seems to be a bug.

Resources
The file should be included as a resource, not as a source. It should en up in the same folder as Info.plist in your build.

First of all, thanks for answering. Could you give me more information about "add it as a resource source not as source"
It seems to be as "resource" in build phase.  (see next coment)
